# Ajax hash in url

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using code from [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/)

In the URL, it is weird; If I were to click on home, it'll go to `example.tld/home#`, but I would like to have the hash on the back. `example.tld/#home`. If I were to go to the contact page, it'll display as `/home#co` … doesn't display the whole word. (contact). I would like `#contact` to replace `#home` when I change the page. Also how can I land on a different page on load instead of `#home` again? Example: click on `example.tld/#contact`, goes to `#contact` page.

Also...Here is the code I have modified from the [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/):

```
 // Check for hash value in URL  
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);  
    var href = $('nav ul li a').each(function(){  
        var href = $(this).attr('href');  
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){  
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #main-content';  
            $('#content').load(toLoad)  
        }  
    });  

    $('nav ul li a').click(function(){  

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #main-content';  
    $('#main-content').hide('fast',loadContent);  
    $('#load').remove();  
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');  
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);  
    function loadContent() {  
        $('#main-content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $('#main-content').show('normal',hideLoader());  
    }  
    function hideLoader() {  
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
    }  
    return false;  

    });
```

Think I should cach some of the selectors that are being repeated?

Also here is the **HTML:**

```
<div id="main-content" class="home">

… content to be loaded

</div>
```

**Nav:**

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

I'm using htaccess so I do not have to include the file extension, but if its needed, the files are .php

Let's say i'm on `#home` and if I click the `#home` link again, it'll reload the same page, is there any way to stop this if i'm already on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
```

to

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
```